# amazon aws auto scaling groups instance name tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

How can I create auto scaling group which create instances with a Name Tag containing  +  ?

Current tag

```
Name    LIVE
```

But I want to change it to

```
Name    LIVE-ap-southeast-1a
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to change the **Key=Name** **Value=LIVE** to **Key=Name** **Value=LIVE-ap-southeast-1a** for instances that are created with an auto scaling group.

When you create an Auto Scaling Group at step **4. Configure Tags** you can specify the tag Key and Value. Make sure the "Tag New Instances" check box is checked (it is by default):

[image]

If you already have an Auto Scaling Group Configured you can select the group and edit it:

[image]

I tested these steps and confirmed that new instances created by auto scaling displayed the correct Key and Value:

[image]

For reference, here is AWS's guide on auto scaling tagging:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASTagging.html

Comment: I want to dynamically tag the availability zone. eg: when new instance is auto created in availability zone A it should tag as LIVE-A, if instance launched in availability zone B it should tag as LIVE-B

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [EC2 user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) script of the EC2 instance to dynamically initialize your instance including tags. The EC2 user data script is set from your EC2 Auto Scaling Launch Configuration/Template.

As an example with EC2 running AWS Linux 2, a bash script can use the [EC2 metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) to fetch the availability zone the instance launched in and its EC2 instance id. Then with the AWS CLI set the Name tag of the instance using the [ec2 create-tags](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html) command.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1

# Get Instance MetaData
AVAILABILITY_ZONE=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
REGION=${AVAILABILITY_ZONE::-1}
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)

# Dynamically set instance name
aws ec2 create-tags --region $REGION --resources $INSTANCE_ID --tags Key=Name,Value=LIVE-$AVAILABILITY_ZONE
```

Your EC2 instance IAM Role will need a policy attached that allows the `ec2:CreateTags` action on EC2 instances. You can use a condition on the policy statement to only allow tags to be created on EC2 instances created from your EC2 Auto Scaling Group to give your role the least privilege needed to create tags.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:CreateTags",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:{aws_region}:{aws_account}:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/aws:autoscaling:groupName": [
                    "prod-as-group"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```